# Proguard application's ClassLoader Error

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard, xsbt-proguard-plugin

Proguard in android application is throwing a Runtime error -

java.security.InvalidParameterException: Unable to locate the specified interface com.example.abc in the application's ClassLoader! A typo?

Could anyone please help to resolve the error.

Comment: Proguard is probably hiding an interface by obfuscating it. You should add exeptions in `proguard-rules.pro`.

Comment: @Abbas How can i add exception for that particular interface